# Faraday's Law or Kirchoff's Loop rule?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image: The circuit]

$$\mathbf{B}=\begin{cases}
B_{0}t ;t \in [0,T]\\
B_{0}T ;t>T
\end{cases}$$

Assume negligible resistance for the connecting wire and other necessary constants.

Should I use Faraday's Law or Kirchoff's Voltage Law? I tried both of them end up with different answers. Also I assumed the area of the loop to be A in the case of Faraday's law. And what's the justification of the method? I think we should use Faraday's here as there is a changing magnetic flux.

Comment: You should focus on just your conceptual issues; don't ask how to actually do your homework problem. I have started the edit, but you should keep going. The conceptual issue of  Kirchoff vs. Faraday you have raised is a good conceptual question.

Comment: Okay I got that. I'll put my solution in the answers to just so I can be sure. @BioPhysicist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kirchoff's Voltage Law is just a restatement that the path integral of $\vec{E}$ around any closed loop is equal to zero.  This is because the voltage drop across any element in a circuit is just the path integral from one side of the element to the other.

In situations where there is a changing magnetic field, however, we have
$$
\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s} = - \frac{d \Phi}{dt}.
$$
(This can be proven using Stokes' theorem and the differential form of Faraday's Law.)  Thus, Kirchoff's Law cannot be expected to hold in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem.  I believe all you need to do is calculate the additional *emf* produced by the B field and **add** it as a second source in the loop (paying attendtion to sign).  As i see it, the loop already has a voltage source, ε, which is a battery (based on the symbol).  So, the answer would be to use both.

Use Faraday to calculate the emf induced by the B field.  Then use kirchoff to find the I that flows as a result of these 2 voltage sources.

Comment: ε is from the battery and area of the loop is A(not mentioned in the question though).

Comment: OK, then as I describe it is the right way to work the problem.  The emf generated by the B field will either add to or subtract from the battery e.  The resulting voltage will drive current flow.  Note that to induce emf from B field requires changing flux through the loop.  Once you reach time T the B field becomes constant so total flux is constant.  Constant flux linking coil means no emf induced...only voltage then will be your battery.

Answer (score 0):

Now since here there is a changing magnetic flux, application of Faraday's law would be advised. And also intuitively makes sense to use this law as when there is a change in $\phi_{B}$, an emf is produced in the loop that may increase or decrease the current flowing depending on the direction of magnetic field.

Now using faraday's law,

$$∮E⃗ ⋅ds⃗ =−\frac{dΦ}{dt}$$
Going clockwise in the loop. Hence taking the area vector from right hand thumb rule, i.e. into the plane.

The integral evaluates to:

$-ε+iR_{1}+iR_{2} ---(1)$

$\phi_{B}=\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{A}=-B_{0}At ; t \in [0,T]$

$\frac{dΦ}{dt}=-B_{0}A\ ; \ t \in [0,T] ---(2)$

$(1)=(2)$

$-ε+iR_{1}+iR_{2}=-(-B_{0}A)$

Rearranging:

$$i=\frac{B_{0}A+ε}{R_{1}+R_{2}}$$

Comment: Do tell me if this is correct

Comment: Looks pretty good, except you’re ignoring t > T.  You need a second equation for that time period

Comment: No problem with that as there’s no changing magnetic flux there. I’m not ignoring it but rather more interested in solving when there is a changing magnetic field. Well for t >T , the $B_{0}A$ will not be there in the numerator.

Comment: Ok, good deal. If anybody's answer helped you should upvote it and/or select one as having answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent sources of emf in this circuit, one being the time-changing B field, the other the battery.  Use simple superposition.  Careful with the direction of the current induced by the B field.

I am new on this site and need time to adapt to the differences between LaTex and MathJax to write any formulas.